# Getting an error in Binary Tree question: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'val'

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, binary-search-tree

```py
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def levelOrder(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[List[int]]:
        if not root:
            return None

        li = []
        curr = root
        li.append([root.val])
        if curr.right and curr.left:
            li.append([self.levelOrder(curr.left.val), self.levelOrder(curr.right.val)])
        elif not curr.right and curr.left:
            li.append([self.levelOrder(curr.left.val)])
        elif curr.right and not curr.left:
            li.append([self.levelOrder(curr.right.val)])
#            elif not curr.right and not curr.left:
        else:
            return li
```

So for the question "102. Binary Tree Level Order Traversal" on LeetCode, I was writing the code. I'm a beginner so can't understand why I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'val'
    li.append([root.val])
```

Even though the root is a Binary Tree node so it should return value yet it is throwing this error.

Tried working everything out but couldn't get any concrete reasoning for the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

- The cause of the error is that you make the recursive call with an `int` as argument instead of a `Node`:

  ```
  self.levelOrder(curr.left.val)
  ```

  ... should be:

  ```
  self.levelOrder(curr.left)
  ```
- `return None` is not what is required. The challenge description says that for an empty tree you should return `[]`.
- The `return li` statement should not only be executed in the `else` clause. You need to *always* return a list, so also in the other cases
- `li.append([root.val])` will not append an `int` to the list, but a list. So that gives you a nested list. Here the square brackets should be removed
- `li.append([self.levelOrder(curr.left.val)])` is even worse: the recursive call will return a list, and then you wrap that list in a list, and then you append that list of list as an item to the list -- this gives you three levels of nested lists which will accumulate as the tree gets larger. You should use the `extend` method instead.
- But even when all of the above is corrected, this is performing a pre-order traversal, not a level order traversal. A level order traversal algorithm has a completely different approach than a pre-order traversal, so almost nothing of your code can be reused. You must start from scratch and look into bread-first traversals.